# How to do math expression from input() in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a situation when I have to convert user's input to int and do math operation:

```
    import ast
    user_input = input()

    if user_input.isdigit():
        print('it is a number:', ast.literal_eval(user_input))
    elif user_input.isalpha():
        print('it is a string')
    elif user_input.isalnum():
        print('it is something mixed')
    else:
        print('can\'t recognize', user_input)
```

The first case **if user_input.isdigit** doesn't work if there is a math expression like **2 + 2** or **5 * 5**. What`s wrong?

Comment: `+` isn't a digit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` if you want to evaluate a expression. Also you need to use `raw_input()` in Python 2

```
>>> user_input = eval(raw_input())
2+3
>>> user_input
5
```

In all other cases , you can use a `map()` function.
Like `user_input = map(int, raw_input())`

**Disclaimer**

Don't use `eval` to take raw sql queries. It can destroy your database.

Comment: `eval` is very broad, it can do some pretty good things other than just evaluating arithmetic operations.

Comment: Who says that he is using Python 2?

Comment: eval() and ast.literal_eval() do not work inside if statement. I don't know why

Comment: @MikayilAliyev Because the whole line isn't printed.

Comment: @DanielFrühauf what do you mean the line isn't printed?

Comment: The if statement is not going to be true if you read the answers from Peter Wood & Ken Wei.

Answer (score 0):

`'2 + 2'` contains spaces and symbols; `.isdigit()` would return `False`.

Perhaps you should do the data checking after stripping away whitespaces and symbols.

Second, `ast.literal_eval` can't do mathematical operations for you. You need `eval()` for that. However, this looks dangerous in your case, so you might want to consider looking up the `asteval` package.

Comment: Yes, because (1) '+' is not a digit, and (2) `ast.literal_eval` can't do mathematical operations.

Comment: this is the sort of situation that `asteval` was designed for:  `eval()` is dangerous in that clever input can easily segfault python, and `ast.literal_eval` is limited to literals, not expressions.

Answer (score -2):

Now it works, but it seems to me, that the code is ugly and not quite right:

```
    user_input = input()

    if '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' in user_input:
        print(eval(user_input))
    elif user_input.isalpha():
        print('it is a string')
    elif user_input.isalnum():
        print('it is something mixed')
    else:
        print('can\'t recognize', user_input)
```